# Gitlab Self Hosted GKE Runners Cache Not Working 403

Tags: gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine

While trying to setup and use cache on GCS on a self hosted Gitlab instance I am getting the following error.

`ERROR: error while generating GCS pre-signed URL: signing blob: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Request had insufficient authentication scopes.`

Gitlab version 15.0

Runners on GKE Cluster

Installed VIA helm chart

Config in helm values file

```
runners:
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      [runners.kubernetes]
        namespace = "{{.Release.Namespace}}"
        image = "ubuntu:16.04"
        [runners.cache]
          Type = "gcs"
          Path = "runner"
          Shared = true
          [runners.cache.gcs]
            BucketName = "my-bucket-name"

  cache:
      secretName: google-application-credentials
```

The service account has `Storage Legacy Bucket Owner` and I even switch the bucket to public access and still got the same error.

While looking at the volumes attached to the runner pods, I also don't see the `google-application-credentials` secret attached, so it makes me think that either something isn't working that is supposed to update update the pods, or I am missing adding a config in my values file.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using the following config instead.

```
[runners.cache]
  Type = "gcs"
  Path = "path/to/prefix"
  Shared = false
  [runners.cache.gcs]
    AccessID = "cache-access-account@test-project-123456.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    PrivateKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nXXXXXX\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
    BucketName = "runners-cache"
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnerscachegcs-section